# Does HTML5 Custom Tag impact SEO?

Tags: seo, html5, tags

For example if to wrap a heading in `<product-title>` and `</product-title>` instead of `h1...h6`.

Is there a mention of the issue somewhere on the Internet?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Semantics does have a value for search engines, that's how they started and it still holds some value.

Answering to your question whether it could impact SEO or not - I would say yes. Custom tags are best to use in scenarios where you don't have to worry about search engines, but for webpages facing the search engines it is best to stick with the standard document model and maintain hierarchy by using the right tags for right purposes. More than search engines it is easier for browsers to understand your better, thus helping the end user in even a small way.

But if you do plan on using custom tags then consider using JSON-LD tags to tell the search engine better about your page's structure.

Comment: Thanks. However, it's strange why Google as the browser's vendor and member of W3C promoted HTML5 custom elements to become a browser standard while as the biggest search engine it still doesn't accept the custom elements as a SEO standard

Comment: Who said that HTML custom elements have become or are being promoted to become a standard in the sense that it should be mostly used? It is promoted as a "standard" in the sense that it should be supported by browsers for when you want to use it, not a standard to replace traditional elements. HTML5 made the tags such as `<header>` `<footer>` and lot more tags a standard to have a semantic meaning and that is what you should be using for SEO purpose.